# Gem List for Chef-Solo

Tags: chef-infra, devops, chef-solo

I am using chef-solo in my environment..I would like to know which gems are installed or bundled in my default installation?

Is there a command that I could execute?
I would like to validate the gems that are included in my current version.

Answer (score 0):

You will have all the gems inside gems folder wherever your chef is installed. You can search for gems folder using find command and view the gems present.

Answer (score 0):

The precise list varies from version to version, currently we ship nokogiri, pry, rb-readline, inspec, and then chef itself and all its dependencies as per normal. You would use the `gem` metadata declaration to include more in most cases.